# ML paper reproducibility

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, research

How can I reproduce results in an ML paper if I don't have the identical resources to train the models as in the paper ? (in my case I only have a laptop spec NVidia gpu and in most of the papers I read models are trained on a minimum of 8 GPU's with 10x more memory than the GPU I use).

I haven't tried a certain method yet and I am currently asking to get some ideas.

Comment: You can't. That's the catch with research that uses a lot of computational resources: it is hard to reproduce because not even modest research labs may have the same resources available.